# I can't load an image in Javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview

I've read many other topics about this in stackoverflow, and yet none of their solutions seem to fit my problem. There are no errors, just a blank stage, and I dont' understand why.

```
public void titleView(Pane pane)
{
    Image img = new Image("file:test.png");

    ImageView title = new ImageView(img);
    title.setImage(img);
    title.setLayoutX(569);
    title.setLayoutY(146);
    title.fitHeightProperty().add(100);
    title.fitWidthProperty().add(100);
    title.setVisible(true);

    pane.getChildren().add(title);

    System.out.println("success!!!");        
}
```

This is the method I've made. The "test.png" file is just a red 100x100 picture made in paint. It's located in the project and in a folder I've made: res/textures/test.png
I did remember to build path to it

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
titleView(pane);
```

I hope somebody can help, thanks

Comment: What is the actual path *relative to your classpath* once the project is built? (E.g. if you made `res` part of the build path, then you should be able to see `textures/test.png` in the build folder and/or jar file). And what is the end aim here? Are these images going to be bundled with the application? Or are you going to load them from some location on the users' file system (e.g. via a file chooser, or in some specified folder external to the application)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this *.getResourceAsStream* :

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("pic.png"));
 title.setImage(image);
```

*getClass().getResource("...")* also throws me NPE in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

It all has to do iwth your file path references...

```
Image img = new Image(YourMainClassName.class.getClass().getResource("test.jpg").toString());
```

Or similar may work

Comment: I tried this and a few other variations, but none seem to work. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException every time.

Comment: Using this method the image has to be in the same location as `YourMainClassName` (i.e in the default package or src folder)

Comment: I'm counting on using many images, and It would become very messy later on. But I tried it nevertheless, and still got a java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem a lot. The way I start to solve it is by making sure the file exits. A lot of the time is basically a wrong file path.

Try:

```
    File file = new File("YourFile.jpg");
    if(file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("file exist!");//I would print file path here.
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("file does not exist!");
    }
```

If the file does not exits, play with your file path: File file = new File("src/img/YourFile.jpg");

If the file exits one of the other mentioned methods should work.